# I installed ubuntu 16.04 on my lenovo G500 wifi off

Tags: wireless

04 on lenovo G500 the wifi seem off meaning regardless seem enable ..can't see any network as is off. I tried few network-manager restart but still nothing .Please can someone help ? Many thanks

Hi the output is:

```
02:00.0 network controller (0280):broadcom corporation BCM43142 80.11b/g/n (14:e4:4365) (Rev 1)
Subsystem : lenovo-g5 BCM43142 802.11/g/n (17aa:0611)
kernel driver in use : bcma-pci-bridge

patrizia@patrizia-Lenovo-G500:~$ lsmod | grep -e acpi

thinkpad_acpi          86016  0

nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi

snd                    81920  18 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_
codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_
hda_intel,thinkpad_acpi,snd_seq_device

video                  40960  3 i915,ideapad_laptop,thinkpad_acpi
```

Comment: try to reinstall with your lenovo connected to the internet with a cable, this way the installation may find a driver for you and download it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: We'd also love to see: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e acpi`

Answer (score 0):

Connect your notebook to UTP network cable and try this:

Check "Additional drivers" and see if driver for broadcom corporation BCM43142 is there and install it - select Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source and press Apply Changes.

My screenshot of Aditional drivers

[image]

If there is no option in Additional drivers try to install it manually from terminal with following command

```
apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

My output is (using wl driver):

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```